# what is $this->vars($vars) in codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

Here is an example.

```
$vars['jscss_src'] = "\n".implode("\n",$aSrc)."\n";
$this->vars($vars);
```

There is an expression `$this->load->vars()` but when googling `$this->vars()` 
Nothing could be found. What is the meaning of it?

Thanks in advance :)

+) actually this expression is coded in the extended Loader core class in codeigniter. Could it be a reason?

Comment: Have a look on this thread post  http://ellislab.com/forums/viewthread/83781/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code almost certain is part of a member function of some class. The `this` is referencing the actual object, the method has been called on. `vars` is another member function of the same class.

Comment: actually this expression is coded in the extended Loader core class in codeigniter. Could it be a reason?

Comment: Then the loader core class has a member named `vars` which (I don't know igniter, sorry) perhaps returns some model defined data into the view.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [documentation](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/loader.html):

> $this->load->vars($array)
>
> This function takes an associative array as input and generates
>   variables using the PHP extract function. This function produces the
>   same result as using the second parameter of the $this->load->view()
>   function above. The reason you might want to use this function
>   independently is if you would like to set some global variables in the
>   constructor of your controller and have them become available in any
>   view file loaded from any function. You can have multiple calls to
>   this function. The data get cached and merged into one array for
>   conversion to variables.

Answer (score 0):

The load->vars function adds the array to an Loader class variable that is used in the load->view function where the array gets extracted. (Is used to pass variables to views)